# Making Android Cursor Serializable

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, serializable

I'm quite new to android and trying to implement a content provider using SQLite. The cursor returned from my query method has to be sent to another instance of app using a socket.

To send the data, I tried to encapsulate a cursor object within a serializable class which I'm then writing to my objectOutputStream which I later found will not work.

I've been reading about Parcelable which seems a bit complex and the only alternative I can think of is building a HashMap out of my cursor.

Is there any better way to this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a ContentProvider, can you just send the content URL with the parameters and then re-run the query in the target app?

Comment: Wouldn't that need the apps to be on the same device? My app will need to send the data to an instance of the same app running on another device.

Comment: Oh! You didn't mention different devices (although duh, I should have figured that out from your references to sockets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to do this, I would just loop through the cursor, read all the data, serialize it to JSON, write it to the socket, and call it a day.

Now if you are one of those programmers with masochistic tendencies, I can offer an alternative.  Consider that when you use a `ContentProvider` through a `ContentResolver`, the cursor data is serialized so it can move from one process to the other.  The main class for this is the `CursorWindow`, which as it turns out is a `Parcelable`.  As the app loops through the cursor, the driver for the cursor fills `CursorWindow`s with data which get parceled and sent back to the app.  You *might* be able to get that whole mechanism to work across a socket.  You would have to do a little reverse engineering of the `AbstractWindowedCursor` class and all its friends to work out the details.  For instance, there is a `CrossProcessCursorWrapper` class that might be helpful to you.

However, be aware that you will be walking into a minefield.  I've never had to get into the internals of data access through a service (i.e. across processes) so I have no idea of all the places where bugs could hide.  `Cursor`s are not required to be synchronized; the user of the `Cursor` has to take care of all the thread safety.  `SQLiteCursor`s have native resources and `CursorWindow` has some type of internal reference counting, so you would have to make sure you're doing all the right things at the right time so that nothing leaks.  With apps on two different devices there may be UID/permissions issues.

So I definitely think it's doable, but for me? I don't have the time to sort through all that stuff.  I'll just stick to my caveman JSON code, thank you very much.

Comment: I tried using the CursorWindow class but I keep running into synchronization problem so I'm gonna go with the JSON approach too. Thanks a lot for your help